# Log the exception and counting the exception in a same method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am tring to `count` the number of `exceptions` happening and log those `exceptions` as well. So what I did is, I created one method `addException` in which I am counting all the exceptions.

`addException` method accepts two parameters, `one is the String`, and other is the `boolean flag` which means whether we want to terminate the program or not because of any exceptions. Meaning, if that flag is true, then I need to terminate the program whenever there are any exceptions.

So if you take a look into my below `catch` block, I have `addException` method call for counting the exceptions and below that method call I am logging the exceptions as well.

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
    LOG.error("Threw a ClassNotFoundException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
    //DAMN! I'm not....
    LOG.error("Threw a SQLException while making connection to database in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am looking for is-

Is there any more cleaner way of doing the same thing? Meaning right now I am counting the exceptions in a method and then printing out the exceptions in the next line inside the catch block.

Comment: More suitable here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/