# Thread Contention while adding the values in a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am tring to `count` the number of `exceptions` happening in the multithreaded code. So for that what I did is, I created one method `addException` in which I am counting all the exceptions using the `AtomicInteger`.

`addException` method accepts two parameters, `one is the String`, and other is the `boolean flag` which means whether we want to terminate the program or not because of any exceptions. Meaning, if that flag is true, then I need to terminate the program whenever there are any exceptions.

So if you take a look into my below `catch` block, I have `addException` method call for counting the exceptions and below that method call I am logging the exceptions as well.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            service.submit(new ReadTask());
    }

class ReadTask implements Runnable {

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

public ReadTask() {

}

@Override
public run() {

    try {

        .........

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
        LOG.error("Threw a ClassNotFoundException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
        LOG.error("Threw a SQLException while making connection to database in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
    }
}

    /**
     * A simple method that will add the count of exceptions and name of
     * exception to a map
     * 
     * @param cause
     * @param flagTerminate 
     */
    private static void addException(String cause, boolean flagTerminate) {
        AtomicInteger count = exceptionMap.get(cause);
        if (count == null) {
            count = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger curCount = exceptionMap.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
            if (curCount != null) {
                count = curCount;
            }
        }
        count.incrementAndGet();

        if(flagTerminate) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any Thread Contention possible with this code? If yes, how can I write `addException` method in a better way to avoid `Thread Contention`?

Is there any more **efficient** way of writing `addException` method here?

Comment: Might be a better candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com (granted it's currently beta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks logically correct, but there is still the possibility of thread contention.

Consider what happens if each thread throws the same exception: they will serialize on updating the `AtomicInteger` keeping track of the exception count.

There's really no easy way around this: if all threads are updating the same piece of data then they pretty much have to serialize. That's not a problem; that's just reality.

There **are** ways you could work around this but it will turn a simple, correct piece of code into a complex nightmare.

The question you should be asking is "Do I **need** to make this more efficient?" Chances are the answer is no since exceptions are, almost by definition, rare. The question of "*How* do I make it more efficient" should only be asked if the answer to the previous question is yes.

Comment: Yeah. Now it makes more sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have one more question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149172/log-the-exception-and-counting-the-exception-in-a-same-method). Can you please help me out there? I haven't got a single help over there.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid contention for threads trying to update the same count, is to have each thread keep its own count, and to summate at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //This check-then-act block can cause two threads can see count as null
    if (count == null) {
        count = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger curCount = exceptionMap.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
        if (curCount != null) {
            count = curCount;
        }
    }
```

Suggestion: 
1) How about a `Map<Class<?>,AtomicInteger>` where Class would be class of the exception.

**UPDATE:**
Try using `ThreadLocals` here each thread will have **its own copy of map** and will update in its own copy. So zero contention.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` returns the existing value if there already is one, so this is OK. The `curCount != null` check means that if this thread tries to insert a value after another thread already has then it will switch to using the already-inserted `AtomicInteger`. It is true that two threads could see `count` as null, but the second one will correct for that.

Comment: true bt the instance of atomic integer is any way created. Just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: Agreed, it's not 100% efficient, but it is still thread-safe in terms of being logically correct in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @CameronSkinner, I thought there was no thread safety issues here. Let me know the way I am doing is right or not. And if not then please suggest me some other way around or how to make it more efficient. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NarendraPathai, Thanks for the suggestion, I believe it was thread safe. Is there any way I can make that more efficient?

Comment: @TechGeeky: The cost of creating the extra `AtomicInteger` is absolutely negligible. I wouldn't bother trying to optimize that away. Remember, premature optimization is a Bad Idea. Only optimize details like this if you can demonstrate that it is *really* a bottleneck.

Comment: @CameronSkinner yes true. But check-then-act is the most common place to make mistakes. So should always be kept in mind.

Comment: I see.. That makes sense. And any Thread Contention possible becasue I have declared that as static. So I think, I need to remove the static method. Right?

Comment: Why do you think the static-ness is a problem?

Comment: I thought I should avoid the static method to handle the storage directly in the map, it's a fairly strong source of contention and will prevent my threads to focus on doing their real work, which is launching and processing queries. Typically, accessing a map has a time complexity in O(log n), and in my code, I am doing  that access twice, and do all sort of checks to make sure that the accounting is correct.

Comment: static is not a problem here. Also as you are leveraging the concurrency of ConcurrentHashMap then it will perform.

Comment: I wonder if you could use ThreadLocal here. Then there would be no contention. But you will have to change your logic for total exceptions

Comment: @TechGeeky: No, accessing a HashMap is typically O(1). Unless you have a crappy hash function, in which case it could be O(n). You say "it's a fairly strong source of contention", but do you have data to back that up? It feels very much like you are micro-optimizing here.